# Can you merge different characters' world views?

Tags: terraria

I am running my own Terraria server (currently the included one, but also want to test TShock) in my network and play with a friend.

Is there a way to for our characters to see parts of the map that the other has uncovered?

Since we can not always play together, it would be great if the characters could exchange about the parts of the world they visited.

To do this seems quite logical to me. Especially since the member also sees the information provided by the equipment (Compass, Depth Gauge, Lifeform Analyzer...) of nearby team members.

I found map files in the characters sub folder. I guess these contain exactly this information. 
As a last resort one could merge this files offline if the format is understood (I am not afraid of binary data and programming ;) but the optimal solution would be server side.

Comment: While I don't know of a tool, if parts of their maps overlap you can use something like GIMP or even Paint to piece them together.

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. oh - i didn't checked their content on detail - just saw binary without further looking at the content. are these regular image files? then this task would be more less difficult to implement than i thought.

Comment: @rivermont-WillB.the fileformat is some proprietary binary. how did you came to your Gimp/Paint suggestion?

Comment: I haven't looked at the files myself. I assumed that they were stored in some image format. What file extension are they?

Comment: Haven't personally tried this but theoretically it could work. I found a tool that loads the .wld file and essentially lets you view the world (http://seancode.com/terrafirma/) now this wont let you edit anything but they posted information on how the data structure for the world works (http://seancode.com/terrafirma/world.html)  I would recommend having a thorough read of this to get a good idea of the file format.  Once you know this, it should be easy enough to merge both .wld files together, either by appending the contents together or using a tool like Beyond Compare.

Comment: @Gorp i think this is an misunderstanding of the question because of an edit that was made by DanmakuGrazer. I do not want to merge .wld files. i want to merge .map files that contain the characters discovery maps. I made a rollback to prevent this.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch ahh, my mistake.  As i said i haven't got it on my current computer so i couldn't check by hand and i just did a bit of snooping and came to that understanding, thinking that .wld would just be Terraria shorthand for 'world'. my mistake.